# generate words list from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, words, mariadb

How can I generate a list of words from a MySQL/MariaDB table using PHP?

I have the following table:

```
id Title
1  A brief history of time
2  philosophy of ecucation
3  introduction to education
4  philosophy and astrophysics
5  astrophysics: astrophysics for dummies
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have MySQL (or PHP) generate a result showing how often a word is used. Preferably each title should increase the counter for a word only by 1 (see id 5). My database contains roughly 10000 titles so fetching them all into one array in php should not be feasible.

```
count word
1     brief
2     philosophy
2(!)  astrophysics <-- this counts only once
1     introduction
etc.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What code do you have that generates the count table you've posted?

Comment: I generated the count table manually just as an example. This is how the result should look like. I could not think of any other solution but to fetch each row individually (with PHP) and then have PHP generate a word list. I think that would be time consuming as the whole database must be fetched by the client. Maybe there is a way of accessing the index of the table with MySQL. As I am just beginning to learn MySQL/PHP this is not a trivial task to me.

Comment: Related to (but not duplicate of) [Count the frequency of each word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410458/count-the-frequency-of-each-word). I'll think of a solution that ignores "duplicate" words.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE Title LIKE '%astrophysics%';
```

Comment: That would work if I queried for specific words. However I need to explore which words are the most popular as I do not know the words to query beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an easy task. You first need to retrieve all words out of your texts, and to do this, you need a kind of separate index table (lookup table) of `id,word` with no primary key, probably with "substring_id" field signifying the position of the `word` in the title of the book id `id`. Then you can do like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word, count(id) as count from lookup
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY word
```

To form this table, you need to have a consistency check (a trigger, likely) on insert, update, delete, that will alter the `lookup` table updating info about text and id. Use this question [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query) as source on how to retrieve a list of words out of a string (aka split by space).